# kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0 to included layout

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I've included layout (with a merge tag) that expects these params:

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="title"
            type="String" />

        <variable
            name="titleOnClick"
            type="kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0"/>

        <variable
            name="icon"
            type="Integer" />
    </data>
```

I'm trying to pass a function from my viewModel to this included layout this way:

```
<include layout="@layout/test_layout"
            android:id="@+id/test_layout"
            app:title="@{@string/test_title}"
            app:icon="@{@drawable/ic_test}"
            app:titleOnClick="@{viewModel.myListener.onTestBtnClick}"/>
```

compilation fails because of `app:titleOnClick="@{viewModel.myListener.onTestBtnClick}`

Any idea how to pass this function to my included layout?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue is with the ViewModel variable is not specified in your layout.

Comment: Its working now?

Comment: no, I had it before. I still can't find a way to pass a function from my viewmodel to my include layout

Comment: you can try by passing viewmodel to include and call the method from there button click

Comment: Yes I know, but i wanted to make it more granular, I want to use it in 2 different cases where each case has a different click event